# Django with UDP socket - What should I use, Twisted Plugin or Django Channels?

Tags: django, udp, twisted

I'm making the Django website and need parsing some data from the UDP socket. I found https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/tap.html , what can help me handle UDP socket very easy, when I embed it to Django project, it doesn't run. how to embed it to Django?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide the piece of code that isn't working for you plus an error message and possibly take a look at [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question here.

Comment: Django only really cares about the Web/HTTP requests.  You could create a UDP server (which can exist in the same codebase) that runs in a separate process from the Django one(s) and handles UDP traffic.  It could also call into parts of the Django code if needed (e.g. to do DB related things) but trying to do too much in one place just complicates things.

Comment: I think an independent server is better, and it will handle UDP traffic and convert it to HTTP request for Django and convert Http request to UDP